# XEN killed my laptop

Tags: virtualization, xen

I need to setup a XEN-Server in order to create a virtualized environment. I have successfully done this in a desktop pc but now when I installed the same in my Dell Inspiron laptop, the installation completed successfully.

However the BIOS says "OPERATING SYSTEM NOT FOUND" and I am not able to run XEN. What's more, I cannot even install any other OS into my laptop! Tried installing WinXP, Win7 and Ubuntu... No gain! I think that installing XEN has created  some serious issues with my laptop's BIOS!

Can anyone please save my day?

Comment: It could be a problem with the hard disk not being detected properly, a disk failure, or a bad MBR on sector 0. Have you tried booting off of a different hard drive?

Comment: No... How to do that?

Comment: Oops, you're on a laptop. It might be a bit more difficult than anticipated. Can you boot off of a USB?

Comment: Boot off after instailling or boot for installing???
XEN does not boot from usb FOR installing.

Comment: You mentioned that you have tried to install other OS's. Have you booted off of USB to install those?

Comment: No.. I tried installing them from CD.
PS: I have tried to install XEN again. This time, it gives me upgrade/install option. Means the XEN installation is perfect and may even run. Can u plz suggest me how to run it?

Answer (score 0):

You should set advanced options at install time.

When the Xen installer starts hit F2 and type the following:

**shell**

Then use either the vim or nano text editors to modify a file.

**nano /opt/xensource/installer/constants.py**
 or
 **vi /opt/xensource/installer/constants.py**

Change the line that reads GPT_SUPORT=True to

**GPT_SUPORT = False**

Save the file, quit the editor and type

**exit**

at the prompt. There is a clash between the BIOS and Xen when GPT is enabled.